# TextBox binding value int, in order to use it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

how to get the value of the textbox and try to use it as int with binding?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedAmount}"/>
```

I have tried like this, but the value of the binding is 0

```
public string SelectedAmount 
{ 
    get { return _selectedAmount; } 
    set { _selectedAmount = value; } 
}
```

That is my main class, but the valau of the textbox stay 0, it does´t change

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

```
    int deposit;
    int weeks;
    int total;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MyClass();

    }

    public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public int _selectedAmount;
        public int SelectedAmount
        {
            get
            {
                return this._selectedAmount;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value != this._selectedAmount)
                {
                    this._selectedAmount = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void BtnCompute_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass ff = new MyClass();
        int cc = ff.SelectedAmount;
        deposit = cc;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how did you define your property? please include relevant code for `SelectedAmount`

Comment: public string SelectedAmount
        {
            get { return _selectedAmount; }
            set { _selectedAmount = value; }
        }
        private string _selectedWeeks;

Comment: so the binding does not work because the property does not support binding.

Comment: I have tried your soluation,but it does´t work

Comment: then I suggest reading some basics first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `Text` to `int` with no effort.

When using bindings, you should either derive the class containing bindable properties from the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the class `DependencyObject`. otherwise the binding will show only the default (initial) values.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public int _selectedAmount;
    public int SelectedAmount 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._selectedAmount;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._selectedAmount)
            {
                this._selectedAmount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[as in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface)

or

```
public class MyClass : DependencyObject
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets or Sets SelectedAmount Dependency Property
/// </summary>
public int SelectedAmount 
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedAmountProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedAmount Property, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedAmountProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedAmount ", typeof(int), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

also do not forget to set the `DataContext` of your view.

```
//in view's constructor:
this.DataContext = new MyClass();
```

or

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:MyClass/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You forgot `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: @AnthonyRussell That is unnecessary because the default binding mode of input controls such as TextBox is TwoWay.

Comment: '_selectedAmount' doesn't need to be initiated, int has '0' as default :). I don't see the point of backingfield-valuechecking in prop's setter... Property wont notify if there is no change (AFAIK). Not sure if setting the Datacontext of a UserControl via XAML is a good idea... how get access to the Instance data? I also wouldn't define Props as Dependency Properties in ViewModel, you'll need an extra handler for each Prop in VM to catch the change and run logic. But that may be more a matter of taste.... No fence, I'm pleased to learn new aspects if they are founded. :)

Comment: @dba good points. `0` was redundant so I removed it - valuechecking is suggested in an MSDN example (if you saw the link below the code) - IMO it doesn't matter where you define your vm as long as you can make it work (matter of taste) - AFAIK binding with DP is way more efficient and handy than INotifyPropChange (which constantly have to break xaml stuff to run a single line of CS code)

Comment: @dba the extra handler actually works very well with xaml since they both use the same infrastructure. I read once that a VM should use INotifyPropChange if it can't be a DepObject (like a poco) but a DP being so similar to xaml makes the executable more responsive. Though I'm not entirely sure what exactly that means!

Comment: @Bijan have overseen the link :) Anyway, I've never seen a Prop is checked, before it's set. :) Must be a matter of taste :). I use DP's in reusable UserControls only for custom Props independent from their DataContext in the UC's Codebehind. In a VM it makes more lines only in my eyes. Can be wrong anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like this,

```
    public void BtnCompute_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyClass ff = new MyClass();
        int amount;
        int.TryParse(ff.SelectedAmount, out amount);
        deposit = amount;
    }
```

Comment: @EyadKelleh, Are you get any value from ff.SelectedAmount? see your output window for binding error.